# CLONE_NEWNS is not effective on Android

Tags: android, namespaces

I'm learning the mount namespace, a isolating mechanism provided by Linux kernel. I wrote a simple C program to test it.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STACK_SIZE (1024 * 1024)
static char container_stack[STACK_SIZE];

char* const container_args[] = {
    "/bin/bash",
    NULL
};

void mounts(void)
{
    syscall(__NR_mount, "proc", "/home/aaa/nstest/", "proc", 0, NULL);
}

int container_main(void* arg)
{
    printf("Container - inside the container!\n");
    errno = 0;
    mounts();
    perror("mount");
    execv(container_args[0], container_args); 
    printf("Something's wrong!\n");
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Parent - start a container!\n");
    int pid = syscall(__NR_clone, CLONE_NEWNS | SIGCHLD, NULL, NULL, NULL,     NULL);
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("clone failed");
        exit(-1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        container_main(NULL);
        exit(0);
    }
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    printf("Parent - container stopped!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And this code working well on my Ubuntu. The directory "/home/aaa/nstest/" is empty in the root mount namespace after it been mounted in new mount namespace.

However, it doesn't work on the Android emulater. The mount propagate to the root mount namespace. Firstly I thought it may caused by the kernel do not support namespace. So I compile the goldfish with all relative CONFIG switch such as CONFIG_NAMESPACE. And it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have the same problem, even after recompile the kernel with all CONFIG_NAMESPACE. I have tried the `unshare -m /bin/bash` command, it works on my archlinux x86_64 box,

so I look deep into the `strace unshare -m /bin/bash` of the command.

```
...
unshare(CLONE_NEWNS)                    = 0
mount("none", "/", NULL, MS_REC|MS_PRIVATE, NULL) = 0
execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
...
```

seams there is a extra call to `mount(...)`. adding the call to my code, it works !

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    const char * source=argv[1];
    const char * target=argv[2];

    if (unshare(CLONE_NEWNS) == -1) {
        printf("Failed to unshare(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    mount("none", "/", NULL, MS_REC|MS_PRIVATE, NULL);

    if (mount(source, target, NULL, MS_BIND, NULL) == -1) {
        printf("Failed to mount %s to %s: %s\n", source, target, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    sleep(50);
    return 0;
}
```